# Linux Kernel thread with wait event interruptible timeout

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have an irq which is called if something on a mcu needs attention. In the irq I do the following.

```
  set_bit(VUSB_MCU_IRQ_GPIO, (void*)&udc->service_request);
  wake_up_interruptible(&udc->service_thread_wq);
```

I want the work be done in a thread and the thread should sleep till something arrives. Therefore I do:

```
while (!kthread_should_stop()) {^

  wait_event_interruptible_timeout(udc->service_thread_wq,
     kthread_should_stop() || udc->service_request, msecs_to_jiffies(500));


  if (kthread_should_stop())
    break;

  if (test_and_clear_bit(VUSB_MCU_IRQ_GPIO, (void*)&udc->service_request)) {
    dev_info(udc->dev, "usb hub service is waken up by mcu irq the hub\n");
  }}
```

Is this the right wait event function. In the wait.h we also see other functions like
"wait_event_interruptible_lock_irq_timeout" and it is not clear which must be used.

I tested also the other but there seems I didnt understand it correctly and some errors appears. If for example I remove the timeout, a message of blocking appears.

Comment: I can't find "wait_event_interruptible_irq_timeout" in wait.h.

Comment: I guess that `^` on the line `while (!kthread_should_stop()) {^` is a typo?

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in the questions code but the code is only for asking the question. I dont know how it happens but the irq wait functions have a lock parameter. I corrected the name but this doesnt change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following function the thread with the irq handling works without any issues.

```
wait_event_interruptible_lock_irq_timeout
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question why `wait_event_interruptible_lock_irq_timeout` solves the problem, because the question does not mention spin-lock usage at all.

Comment: Yes, I also don't know why its working but it does.